# SQL - using ANSI standard

Tags: sql, postgresql

My below query using two select statements works:

```
create or replace view q2 as
select count(p.id) nstudents,
(select count(p.id) nstaff
from people p, staff s where p.id = s.id)
from people p, students s where p.id = s.id;
```

but when i include a third sub query:

```
create or replace view q2 as
select count(p.id) nstudents,
(select count(p.id) nstaff,
(select count(p.id) nboth
from people p, students s, staff t where p. id = s.id and p.id = t.id)
from people p, staff t where p.id = t.id)
from people p, students s where p.id = s.id;
```

it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 3: (select count(p.id) nstaff,
```

Am i making some mistake while including a third query or is there a limit of just 2 nested select statements?

Comment: Please describe what you want the query to do.  Also, I am removing all the specific database tags.  You can add back the *one* that is appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited with the expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with the additional sub-query fails because you insert the second sub-query into the first, when it should come after it like this:

```
select count(p.id) nstudents,
(select count(p.id) from people p, staff t where p.id = t.id) nstaff ,
(select count(p.id) from people p, students s, staff t where p. id = s.id and p.id = t.id) nboth 
from people p, students s where p.id = s.id;
```

However, the query could just as well be written using conditional aggregation (and to use explicit ANSI standard joins) like this:

```
select 
    sum(case when s.id is not null then 1 end) nstudents,
    sum(case when t.id is not null then 1 end) nstaff,
    sum(case when s.id is not null and t.id is not null then 1 end) nboth
from people p
left join students s on p. id = s.id  
left join staff t on p.id = t.id
```